# C++ code returning multiple duplicate characters

Tags: c++, string, duplicates

This is my code to print duplicate character in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char string[80];

    cin.getline(string,80);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){        
        for(int j=i+1;j<strlen(string);j++){
            if(string[i]==string[j]){
                if(string[i] != ' ')               
                    cout<<string[i]<< " ";               
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is `ravuri`, the output is `r`

If the input is `malayalam`, the output is:

```
malayalam
m
a
l
a
a
```

The code is supposed to print `m a l` . Why is it printing the same character multiple times instead of one time?

Comment: Because second/third `'a'` has also duplicates...

Comment: Use a debugger and step through it, and also welcome to the new age of  c++ that has `std::string`

Comment: @Jarod42 What should I do to print only 1 `a`, 1 `m` and 1 `l` ?

Comment: Do you have to print them in that order?

Comment: Avoid using `string` as a variable name, it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @DebarthaPaul `string` is not a keyword, but a very commonly used class from `std`, so it is confusing (in particular when `using namespace std`, something to avoid as well).

Comment: @prapin yeah, my bad...sorry. This should be avoided...

Comment: I recommend either using `std::map<char, int>` for managing character frequencies, or `int array[26]` (and using the letter as an index into the array).  To make things easy, you could set the array capacity to 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzing your codes, your code check the only characters rear to any character.
That is, if you input `malayalam` and i is 1 while `for` operates, your code check if `a` exists in `layalam`.

Then, there are three `a`s. However, your code doesn't print these `a`s all.
Your code will print `a` only once.

Therefore,

```
i=0 → string[0]='m' → m
i=1 → string[1]='a' → a a a
i=2 → string[2]='l' → l
i=3 → string[3]='a' → a a
i=4 → string[4]='y' →
i=5 → string[5]='a' → a
i=6 → string[6]='l' →
i=7 → string[7]='a' →
i=8 → string[8]='m' →
```

By this progress, your code will print the characters along your input.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is a one to one copy from a blog post "codespeedy.com".

Here it is:

[How to print duplicate characters from a given string in C++](https://www.codespeedy.com/print-duplicate-characters-from-a-given-string-in-cpp/)

The answer to your question is given in the section Explanation:

> Print the duplicate values each time any duplicate character is detected

So, this piece of code will print the duplicate values **each time** any duplicate character is detected.

This has been posted by user Yash Shakya. Unfortunately, and I am really very sory to say, the code has *nothing* to do with C++. The quality is low:

- Do not include <string.h> in C++ program
- Never use `using namespace std;`
- Do not use C-Sytle arrays
- Try to avoid to use the names of the most popular C++ type `string` as a variable name

This program is pure C-COde with the usage of `std::cout`

"CodeSpeedy" is advertising with

> Hire us for your software development, mobile app development and web development project.

They should be really careful, what is posted on their page . . .